# xarray DataSet as container for temporally incompatible time series

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have started using xarray as a container for multidimensional time-series data. Naturally, I thought the `DataArray` would work well for contiguous data blocks and the `DataSet` could contain several `DataArray` instances. The problem, however, is that that each `DataArray` instance is getting padding with NaNs for every value of the shared "time" axis which is not only a pain to deal with but a potential explosion of memory usage. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# create first example data array

data = np.random.rand(1000, 100)
t1 = np.datetime64('2015-01-01')
td = np.timedelta64(1_000_00, 'ns')
time_1 = np.arange(data.shape[0]) * td + t1
distance = np.arange(data.shape[1]) * 1

coords = {
    'time': time_1,
    'distance': distance,
}
ar_1 = xr.DataArray(data, dims=list(coords), coords=coords)

# create second example data array

t1 = np.datetime64('2019-01-01')
td = np.timedelta64(1_000_000, 'ns')
time_2 = np.arange(data.shape[0]) * td + t1

coords = {
    'time': time_2,
    'distance': distance,
}
ar_2 = xr.DataArray(data, dims=list(coords), coords=coords)

# create dataset

ds = xr.Dataset({1: ar_1, 2: ar_2})

# the size of ds[1] has doubled
print(ds[1].shape)  # (2000, 100)

# and the extra elements are just NaNs
print(ds[1].isnull().sum)  # 100_000
```

Is there a way to keep this from happening? I thought about renaming the time axis for each `DataArray` but this seemed like a nasty hack. Perhaps there is a better way to do this, or maybe I am just misunderstanding how `DataSet` ought to be used?

I also need to be able to effectively handle `DataArray`s which might have different sampling rates.

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: my understanding of either ``xarray`` or ``netcdf`` is that: Coordinates (or dimensions) are universal, they are applied for all variables (data fields). whether there is data or not for a certain variable (data field). That is why it generates "Nan" to fill the array.

Comment: Ok, so I suppose I am stuck implementing my own container for `DataArray` instances if I don't want this behavior?

Comment: I was aware of your kind of issue before, but not this size. Currently I think that it is the fact that you may have to face if you insist putting "time" into coordinates. If you use ``xr.merge`` to combine them, the results are the same. To my knowledge, the only way around is to put corresponding "time arrays" as different data fields. Hope others can have better ideas.

Comment: Apart from ``xarray`` or say ``netCDF files``, another file format for multidimensional dataset is ``hdf5``, but I am not very familiar with that, it may or may not solve your issue.